# Automatic vertical alignment of a single float on a dedicated page

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

In my large latex document, I have some figures which take a considerable height of the page (80-95%). Latex puts each of these figures alone on a page, aligned on top. I would like to have each figure aligned vertically to center. Is that possible, and if so, how? :)

Comment: As the answers tell, centering is the usual behavior; however it's the whole block (figure and caption) that's vertically centered.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm curious which documentclass you're using, as "normal" behavior (as defined in the LaTeX kernel file `latex.ltx`) is to *center* the float vertically on a floats-only page.

If you need to get the float to be centered on a floats-only page, you should add the following instructions to your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother
```

To have the figure/table be aligned at the top, you would delete the `plus 1fil` after `0pt` in the instruction setting the length of the `\@fptop` variable.

By default, LaTeX will place a large float on a page by itself if the float's height exceeds 50% of the parameter `\textheight`. To change this threshold to, say, `0.75`, you should issue the command `\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{0.75}`. Happy TeXing!

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question, in my opinion, he/she is only interested in a vertical centered solution (not top-aligned) *and* there was no mention of horizontal centering.

Comment: @Werner -- Yes, I initially misread the question, and have revised it since then. :-)

Comment: Consider using `\@dblfptop` and `\@dblfpbot` for two-column floats in two-column documents.

Answer (score 11):

The `[p]` float placement specifier puts the float (`figure` or `table`) on a page of its own, vertically centered. The following MWE illustrates that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering\rule{0.8\linewidth}{0.5\textheight}
  \caption{A big figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: Vertically centered image on a page]

Note that by specifying the optional `[p]` parameter to your float, only that float will appear on the corresponding page.

Comment: I think the OP's issue is that his/her floats on floats-only pages are aligned along the page's top margin instead of being centered vertically. This must be happening because he/she is using a document class or some package that overrides LaTeX's default setup of centering the float vertically on a floats-only page. Will using the `[p]` placement specification solve this lack-of-vertical-centering issue?

Comment: @Mico: It may if they still include the figure inside a designated **float**, since they abide by the regular optional parameter for placement convention. However, if the documentclass provides a new **environment** (not a float), then neither of our solutions will do the trick; your's hooks on float-related spacing.

Comment: I'm using "book" documentclass, with a lot of packages, most of them are recommended by our print service. Indeed, after your pointer (fptop) I started looking, and yes, there it was --- forcing top alignment.