# Why are float objects centered vertically on new pages?

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic vertical alignment of a single float on a dedicated page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28067/automatic-vertical-alignment-of-a-single-float-on-a-dedicated-page)

Why are float objects centered vertically on new pages if they don't fit on the page where they are added to? See MWE below.

```
\documentclass{report}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-3]
  \begin{figure}[htb!]
   \centering
   \rule{7cm}{7cm}
  \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

The 7x7cm square is too big to fit on the same page as the `\lipsum` text. It's moved to a new page. That's okay. But why is it centered vertically? And how can I move this object to the top of the page?

[image]

Comment: Well, no, I want to *avoid* automatic vertical alignment.

Comment: The question title may be misleading, but the accepted answer also contains the answer to your question.