# Single figure is centered on next page?

Tags: floats, alignment

I have a figure, a formula, close to the end of my chapter and it doesn't have enough space on that "last" page.
LaTeX decides to put it on the next page - this is fine, and expected.

But it puts the figure there centered vertically. How can I change that (in the best case for all figures, not just one)?

My question is kind of the opposite of [Automatic vertical alignment of a single float on a dedicated page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28067/automatic-vertical-alignment-of-a-single-float-on-a-dedicated-page).

Comment: [How to place a float at the top of a floats-only page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28556/134144) might be related.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you, the accepted answer contains the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother
```

by the most helpful answer on [How to place a float at the top of a floats-only page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/how-to-place-a-float-at-the-top-of-a-floats-only-page).
There is more information about how and why it works :).