# Figure is leaving a large gap when moving to next page

Tags: overleaf

Any idea why there is a large gape between the top of the page and the figure as can be seen in the image below. I can understand that the figure is moved into the next page because space isn't enough but why is leaving the gape. Also, what is the best option to use for figures in between paragraphs to stop this issue from happening please? Many Thanks

```
\subsection{Experiment 6}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{images/image_filtering.png}
\end{center}
\caption{}
\label{fig:image_filtering}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{TesnorBoard_Graphs/Exp06_Tensorboard.png}
\end{center}
\caption{}
\label{fig:exp06}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: When a float lands on an empty page it gets vertically centered; that's the standard behaviour. You could top-align it as described [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28068/82917).

Comment: Is it using this command \renewcommand\floatpagefraction{0.75}? I have tried doing this but it didn't work. I have also tried using [p]. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, I meant the bit about `\@fptop`.

Comment: Thanks! Would this go into the document preamble or before the figure?

Comment: you are preventing figures going on a float page by using `[ht]` but the image you show shows them on a float page so presumably they could not be placed at all and drifted to the end of the document (or `\clearpage`) by default float pages are vertically centred so you get space above and below.

Comment: Many Thanks, David! I have used the \clearpage that worked perfectly.